# After deploying java web application giving 404– Internal Server Error

Tags: java, web, heroku, deployment, web-applications

I am trying to deploy my java web application in Heroku from using eclipse IDE follow by this link:
https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-java-applications-to-heroku-from-eclipse-or-intellij-idea.

I have use WAR file to deploy this project.I have used mysql database locally.

This is github link of my project:
https://github.com/sachin1830/SmOnlineExamProject.

This is my website link:

[https://onlineexam1830.herokuapp.com/](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh9V1.png).

The index page working fine but when i am getting error when I am trying to login.

`Error: HTTP Status 500 – Internal Server Error ,HTTP Status 404 – Not Found showing.`

**This is my first project and i am new in this please give me suggestions why this error coming and how i can resolve this error?**
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yh9V1.png)

Steps to repro the issue:

1. open website https://onlineexam1830.herokuapp.com/
2. Click on login on top
3. Enter username as nn
4. Enter password as uu

Expected:
User should be able to login

Actual:
Got error as 404.

Locally everything is working fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is, the application is not connected to database. Here is a video I found which explains how to deploy a java application with tomcat server + mySQl in heroku.
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I9XqYN920hI.

[The video also explain the steps to follow if you are using Maven or if you are not using Maven]